# react-native compile apk

Tags: android, android-sdk, react-native

Пытаюсь скомпилировать приложение на react-native из готовой [репы](https://github.com/adbayb/react-native-responsive)
что я сделл:
установил java
установил sdk  и выкачал компоненты которые я думаю нужны
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой [билд](https://github.com/adbayb/react-native-responsive/blob/master/example/android/app/build.gradle)

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.reactnativeresponsive"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

}

прописал JAVA_HOME и ANDROID_HOME в .bashrc(а то ошибки вылетали)

запускаю билд командой
./gradlew assembleRelease
результат -> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /home/igor/sdk/tools

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить данную ошибку?

**UPD**
пробывал скомпилить https://github.com/spencercarli/react-native-push-notification-how-to  тоже та же ошибка, думаю что то из моим SDK что то не "то", ищу причину.

Comment: Попробуй targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: попробывал, http://cropme.ru/3d234be89b2aead18fe6b7dd427412e7 , не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я дела это криво, но у меня прокатило

Заходишь в AndroidStudio

1) Жмешь открыть проект и там выбираешь папку android в своем проекте

2) Жмешь вкладку build->Generate Signed APK

3) там в окне жмешь Create New

4) Заполняй там все (key alias я делал my-key-alias и в сохрани его в \android\app\my-release-key.keystore);

5) дальше вроде надо дописать в android/app/build.gradle следующее

```
android {
...
    signingConfigs { 
       release { 
           storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE) 
           storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD 
           keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS 
           keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD 
           } 
    }
    buildTypes { 
        release { 
        ... 
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release 
        } 
    }

...
}
```

6) в файле gradle.properties в папке android(если что закинь его и в android/.gradle) допиши

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore 
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias 
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=тут твой пасс 
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=тут твой пасс
```

7) заходишь через консоль в папку android твоего проекта и пишешь в консоле "gradlew assembleRelease" и поидее заработает. Файл будев в android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk

PS способ кривой, но у меня работает

Comment: делал приблизительно так же. Оказалось там туториал чуть прошляпил и не доконца сразу дочитал. там четко написано https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html нужно только всмотреться.

Comment: Самое главное не написал то, в твоем случае поможет тебе добавить в папку проекта файл local.properties и дописать там путь в Android SDK в виде "sdk.dir=C:\\AdnroidSDK\\SDK"

Comment: я уже сгенерил все ок) делал на линуксе